# Schreibweise und Aussprache von aus dem Englischen stammenden Akronymen im Plural

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, grammaticality, grammatical-number

Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob Akronyme, die von der englischen Sprache entlehnt sind, im Plural *mit* oder *ohne* "-s" am Ende geschrieben und ausgesprochen werden.

Ich selbst verwende in der Umgangssprache zum Beispiel "PCs". Ist das streng genommen falsch? Gibt es dazu eindeutige Vorschriften, die das regeln?

Comment: +1 Wie sieht das insbesondere bei weiblichen Acronymen wie CPU aus. Am Artikel kann man es dann ja auch nicht erkennen, ob Einzahl oder Mehrzahl gemeint ist.

Comment: Sehr  interessante Frage!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Die deutsche Wikipedia meint u. a. Folgendes zum s-Plural:

> Heute gehört die s-Endung zum Standard
>   der deutschen Pluralbildung. Sie wird
>   immer verwendet, wenn keine andere
>   Möglichkeit vorhanden ist (unter
>   anderem, wenn man das Wort nicht durch
>   Analogie zu anderen Pluralformen
>   einordnen kann), zum Beispiel bei
>   Akronymen und vielen Fremdwörtern, vor
>   allem solchen englischer oder
>   französischer Herkunft

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plural#Der_s-Plural

Ob das eine allgemeingültige Regel ist, kann ich nicht sagen, aber ich habe hier einen Duden (23. Auflage, 2004), der als Plural von PC (Personal Computer) PCs angibt.

Comment: +1 stimme ich vollkommen zu. Da ich aus der IT komme kann ich ergänzen: Wenn die englische Aussprache verwendet wird, verwendet man den englischen Plural, bei eingedeutschten Begriffen und Abkürzungen wird das Plural-S mit eingedeutscht (auch Dollars)

Comment: 1+ ich würde noch ergänzen, dass Abkürzungen, die auf -S, -X enden, gerne mal mit -e/-en oder ohne Veränderung in den Plural gesetzt oder ganz ausgeschrieben werden. "Verschiedene CMSe und MISe im Vergleich" "Er hat mehrere SOS gesendet." "Es waren 93 PAX an Bord."

Answer (score 2):

Ich denke, dass du hier einen sehr speziellen Fall erwischt hast, denn der Plural des Wortes "(der) Personalcomputer" ist "(die) Personalcomputer".

Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/PC_Personal_Computer) sagt: die PC, die PCs

Man beachte, dass die von dir erwähnte Variante lediglich an zweiter Stelle steht.

Comment: Ich würde Personalcomputer oder Personal-Computer im Deutschen schreiben.

Comment: Inzwischen schreibt der Duden: "Plural: die PCs, selten: PC".